# CakePHP 3: can't save with associated model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am saving model data in my controller fine after a get. Now I need to get an associated model for some work after the save.

Now the model will not save. I don't want to save the associated model. I can't see why it might fail.

```
$this->request->allowMethod('ajax');

$modulesEmployee = $this->ModulesEmployees->get($this->request->data['id'], [
    'contain' => ['CourseModules']
]);

$update = $modulesEmployee->toArray();
$update['completed_on'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$update['completed'] = true;

$modulesEmployee = $this->ModulesEmployees->patchEntity($modulesEmployee, $update);

if ($this->ModulesEmployees->save($modulesEmployee)) {
    // Do some work with the associated CourseModules

} else {
    $data['response'] = "Error: ModulesEmployees could not be saved";
    $this->response->statusCode(400);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `toArray`, instead of just patching with an array containing `completed_on` and `completed`?

Comment: You should see whether `$modulesEmployee` has any validation errors or  not.

Comment: I assume since that the main model saves ok without the association and the association is not set to save and so no validation check on it that validation is ok. I also set validation to false in the save to make sure. Could it be that the association still gets validated even though it us not set to save?

Comment: yes good point on using the `toArray`, thanks